# Filtering choice fields in "real time" in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I am having some issues filtering values in my choice fields.

Here is my model for my application:

```
from django.db import models

class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Rank(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Member(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    rank = models.ForeignKey(Rank, verbose_name = 'Member Rank')
    mainrole = models.ForeignKey(Role, related_name = 'main_role', blank=False)
    secondaryrole = models.ForeignKey(Role, related_name = 'secondary_role', blank=False)
    picture = models.ImageField(
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        upload_to='member/pictures/',
        )


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Just to clarify. A Member can have one `Rank`, and from that `Rank`, up to 2 different `Roles`. However, `Ranks` can have 'n' types of `Roles`.

Two issues I'm having:

1. In the admin, the `Rank`'s name appears in the choice-field as many times as there are `Roles` attached to it. Is there a way for me to get rid of the repeated names and leave just one record of it? *This might have something to do with how I modelled my classes, I am sort of new to Django.*
2. If I choose a `Rank`, I need for the choice-fields of his two `Roles` to be filtered for the `Roles` available for that `Rank`, before the user even hits save (ajax-esque). Is there a way to do this? How?

Thank you for your time.

Editing with the code from my model admin:

```
class MemberInlineFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super(MemberInlineFormset, self).add_fields(form, index)
        roles = Role.objects.none()
        if form.instance:
            try:        
                rank = form.instance.rank
            except Rank.DoesNotExist:
                pass   
            else:  
                roles= Role.objects.filter(role__within=Rank.role)
        form.fields['mainrole'].queryset = roles
        form.fields['secondaryrole'].queryset = roles



class MemberInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Member
    formset = MemberInlineFormset
```

Comment: Your problem can definitely be solved. As far as I remember, I have done something similar long time back. Could you please give some/more details on the code written for the Member Model's Admin?

Comment: Hey @SandipAgarwal, I edited my original post and added the code. It wouldn't fit here in this comment box, I'm not sure that was the right thing to do, kinda new to stackoverflow as well. Thanks!

Comment: No problems. The next put **UPDATE** and then your code (this just an example that you could follow). And to use SO, refer the **meta** site as well. I would look into your problem and try my best to come up with a solution to the problem.

Comment: Question: Member is inline to which Model? Please give the model's and the respective admin's code. I need these information so that I can reproduce your problem on my system.

Comment: According to you current model design, `Rank` has a `foreignkey` to `Role`, which implies, many-to-one relationship from Rank to Role. But, as far I understood, you require the other way round. If I am wrong, please do correct me else your code/model design. Moreover, please take a look at the E-R Diagram that you must have designed.